# DomPDF does not download file for AJAX request on Laravel

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I'm working on '`DomPDF`' using Ajax Post request on Laravel project. Below is ajax code.

```
       $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('screen.pdfticket') }}",
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                id:$('#screenid').val()
            },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

And below is code in controller.

```
    $customPaper = array(0,0,216,158);
    $pdf->loadView("screen.ticket" , [ 
        'clinic' => 'clinic name' , 
        'queno' => $screen->que
    ])->setPaper($customPaper, 'landscape');
    return $pdf->download($screen->que .'.pdf');
```

I can get correct response but it's not readable format. I would like to save in pdf format after ajax called success instead. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're making the request using AJAX, you need a way to have the browser load the resource.

There are ways to go but not limited to the following:

- Return the resource URL in the response to the AJAX request then make a separate browser request to load the resource.
- Make a blob of the resource response to the AJAX request then load it from the blob's URL.

   This is shown in the example below.

```
function downloadFile(response) {
  var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'})
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  location.assign(url);
} 

$.ajax({
  url: "{{ route('screen.pdfticket') }}",
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    id: $('#screenid').val()
  }
})
.done(downloadFile);
```

Comment: Dear Oluwafemi Sule, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use stream() to stream created PDF to browser and use output() to get a correct return format. See https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage for more information.